# Does Scimap work with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, watershed, catchment-area

Does anybody know if Scimap ( http://www.scimap.org.uk ) works with QGIS?

I know it is supposed to operate with ArcGIS and SAGA but as I am very much a beginner with QGIS I would like to know if its possible to run the software before I spend a lot of time trying to get it going.

I am running QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour on a rather elderly 8 Mb Macbook Pro

Answer (score 2):

Currently SCIMAP does work directly with QGIS. You can do the calculations within SAGA-GIS using the version available on www.scimap.org.uk and then export the grids and shapefiles from there to QGIS to analysis and cartographic presentation.

Comment: Hopefully you don't mind pasting hyperlink to your video tutorial [**my.scimap exporting to QGIS using WMS**](http://www.scimap.org.uk/2016/08/my-scimap-exporting-to-qgis-using-wms/) here, which shows the steps to link SCIMAP with QGIS.